# Trying to update SQL tables using Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sql-update

I am building a database of 8 tables and I am using Java Frames to build a UI that would perform following functions:

Insert, Delete, Update, Search and Select.

All the functionalities work well except for update. Following is the code for update:

```
   stmt_update = conn_update.createStatement();
   stmt_update.executeUpdate("UPDATE Conference SET C_NAME = '" + confname + "', C_YEAR = " + yr
                + ", START_DATE = to_timestamp('" +stdate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'), END_DATE = to_timestamp('" +enddate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'),"
                + "COUNTRY = '"+country_update+"', CITY = '"+city_update+"', VENUE = '"+venue_update+"',"
                + ",  CONTACT_EMAIL = '"+c_email_update+"' where conference_id = '" + confid + "'");
```

Table structure is:

```
(
Conference_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
C_Name varchar(20),
C_Year numeric(4,0),
Start_Date date,
End_Date date,
Country varchar(10),
City varchar(10),
Venue varchar(10),
Contact_Email varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Conference_ID)
);
```

Error is:

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column
>   specification

I thought there was something to do with the date inputs.

Any suggestions would help greatly.

Thanks.

-----**Update**--------------
Tried using prepare Statement

```
stmt_update = conn_update.prepareStatement("UPDATE Conference SET C_NAME = '" + confname + "', C_YEAR = " + yr
                    + ", START_DATE = to_timestamp('" +stdate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'), END_DATE = to_timestamp('" +enddate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'),"
                    + "COUNTRY = '"+country_update+"', CITY = '"+city_update+"', VENUE = '"+venue_update+"',"
                    + ",  CONTACT_EMAIL = '"+c_email_update+"' where conference_id = '" + confid + "'");
            stmt_update.executeUpdate("UPDATE Conference SET C_NAME = '" + confname + "', C_YEAR = " + yr
                    + ", START_DATE = to_timestamp('" +stdate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'), END_DATE = to_timestamp('" +enddate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'),"
                    + "COUNTRY = '"+country_update+"', CITY = '"+city_update+"', VENUE = '"+venue_update+"',"
                    + ",  CONTACT_EMAIL = '"+c_email_update+"' where conference_id = '" + confid + "'");
```

Still getting the same error.

**Error**:

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column
>   specification

Comment: Print the generated statement and add the result to this question. You are also wide open to SQL injection. Better use a `PreparedStatement` (and I wouldn't be surprised if that your error goes away then as well).

Comment: If you tried using a prepared statement, please add it to the question. It would be better to fix the prepared statement than the badly built, insecure SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Apparently it was a comma that was causing the problem.

Comment: That's not how a `PreparedStatement` should be used. Please read the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   stmt_update = conn_update.createStatement();
   stmt_update.executeUpdate("UPDATE Conference SET C_NAME = '" + confname + "', C_YEAR = " + yr
                + ", START_DATE = to_timestamp('" +stdate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'), END_DATE = to_timestamp('" +enddate +"','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'),"
                + "COUNTRY = '"+country_update+"', CITY = '"+city_update+"', VENUE = '"+venue_update+"',"
                + ",  CONTACT_EMAIL = '"+c_email_update+"' where conference_id = '" + confid + "'");
                   __ Here one extra comma is exist.
```

Those two commas causing the error.

So your code should be:

```
   stmt_update = conn_update.createStatement();
   stmt_update.executeUpdate("UPDATE Conference SET C_NAME = '" + confname + "', C_YEAR = " + yr + ", " 
                + "START_DATE = to_timestamp('" + stdate + "','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'), END_DATE = to_timestamp('" + enddate + "','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:ss.FF1'), "
                + "COUNTRY = '" + country_update + "', CITY = '"+city_update+"', VENUE = '"+ venue_update + "', "
                + "CONTACT_EMAIL = '" + c_email_update + "' WHERE conference_id = '" + confid + "'");
```

Comment: The code worked beautifully. Thanks a ton. Silly me. Should have checked the commas.

Comment: @shubhs9: Some time small typos kill our time, need some one's view can solve that. Happy to help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

this to much use this :

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement stm=your_conn_variable.prepareStatement("UPDATE table_name set field_name=?,seconde_field=? ");
//
stm.setString(1,your_value);
stm.setString(2,your_seconde_value);
stm.executeUpdate();
//will not have to write all this lines and forget all ' , ;
```

here is an example like your case :

```
stmt_update = conn_update..prepareStatement( "UPDATE Conference SET C_NAME = ?")
stmt_update.setString(1,confname);
stmt_update.executeUpdate();
```